# Scroll tableview to the top when tapping tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I need to scroll table view all the way up when selecting the tab bar item.
I tried this but it does not work.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    let tabBarIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex
    if tabBarIndex == 0 {

        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        MyViewController().tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
    }
}
```

The method is called but the tableView does not scroll to the top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you're creating a new `MyViewController` instance rather than accessing the one on screen. You'll want to access the viewController already created and luckily the this delegate method hands that to you.

Change this line

```
MyViewController().tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
```

to

```
let myViewController = viewController as? MyViewController
myViewController.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
self.tableviewObject.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
```